# AnimationDrawable in an AppWidget

Tags: android, android-animation, android-appwidget

I've been trying to add an AnimationDrawable in one of my app widgets. I create an xml resource file looking like this. It displays images of a led with the light on and off (so the animation is a blinking led).

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/time_circuits_led_on"
        android:duration="500"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/time_circuits_led_off"
        android:duration="500"/>

</animation-list>
```

When I installed my AppWidget on my phone, I saw no animation and after some research found that you can't animate drawable in an app widget.

I unlocked my phone a couple of minutes later, and the led was blinking, meaning the animation was working. Nowhere in my AppWidgetProvider do I call the AnimationDrawable#start() method, and so it should'nt be blinking, yet it is.

I locked and unlocked it again severall times, and sometimes the led blinks, sometimes it doesn't. If it blinks (sometimes) maybe there is something I can do to make sure it always blinks.

I'm running this on a Galaxy Nexus, running Android 4.1.1. I also tested this on a phone on Android 2.3.3 and the led never blinks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that animation is *not* supported, as it would be a pretty serious battery hog. Perhaps whatever you are seeing on your Galaxy is some undefined behavior. If you really must have a blinking LED, perhaps you could have a background service broadcast a widget update message every 500ms? I don't necessarily think this is a great idea though.

Comment: I agree with you, from what i've read it shouldn't be blinking, yet it does, and regularly, so it must be the AnimationDrawable doing this.

Comment: I think the way to accomplish what you're trying to do is use a ViewFlipper, it is supported in RemoteViews. Though, in terms of battery use that doesn't look right.

Comment: @YuliaRogovaya thanks for the tip, this really does work. As for the battery I will benchmark how much intense this is , I'll benchmark it. If you'd like to make this an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: You're welcome! I'll make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to accomplish what you're trying to do is use a ViewFlipper, it is supported in RemoteViews. Though, in terms of battery use that doesn't look right.